# Error exceuting Appwrite function from the client

Tags: appwrite

I'm running into problems while trying to execute my first Appwrite Cloud function from the client. The function should create a new database with the same ID and team name as the team that was just created:

Error:

```
An internal curl error has occurred within the executor! Error Msg: Operation timed out
```

From the log:

```
No logs recorded
```

The cloud function:

```
const sdk = require("node-appwrite");
module.exports = async function (req, res) {
  const client = new sdk.Client();
  const database = new sdk.Databases(client);
  if (
    !req.variables.APPWRITE_FUNCTION_ENDPOINT ||
    !req.variables.APPWRITE_FUNCTION_API_KEY
  ) {
    console.warn(
      "Environment variables are not set. Function cannot use Appwrite SDK."
    );
  } else {
    client
      .setEndpoint(req.variables.APPWRITE_FUNCTION_ENDPOINT)
      .setProject(req.variables.APPWRITE_FUNCTION_PROJECT_ID)
      .setKey(req.variables.APPWRITE_FUNCTION_API_KEY)
      .setSelfSigned(true);
  }
  const payload = JSON.parse(req.variables.APPWRITE_FUNCTION_DATA);
  const promise = database.create(payload.teamId, payload.teamName);
  promise.then(
    function (response) {
      req.json(response);
    },
    function (error) {
      req.json(error);
    }
  );
};
```

Calling the function from the client:

```
import { useFunction } from "react-appwrite";

const setupTeamDatabase = useFunction("647687110d37ce2558c1");

const teamDetails = JSON.stringify({
  teamId: createTeam.$id,
  teamName: createTeam.name,
});
const createDatabase = await setupTeamDatabase.mutateAsync(teamDetails);
```

From appwrite.json:

```
{
  "$id": "647687110d37ce2558c1",
  "name": "setupTeam",
  "runtime": "node-16.0",
  "path": "functions/setupTeam",
  "entrypoint": "src/index.js",
  "ignore": ["node_modules", ".npm"],
  "execute": ["users"],
  "events": [],
  "schedule": "",
  "timeout": 15
}
```

package.json

```
{
    "node-appwrite": "^9.0.0"
    "appwrite": "^11.0.0",
    "react-appwrite": "^0.4.2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> An internal curl error has occurred within the executor! Error Msg: Operation timed out

This usually occurs because there is some error in the function or your code is timing out. Some things you should consider doing:

1. Ensure the `APPWRITE_FUNCTION_ENDPOINT` and `APPWRITE_FUNCTION_API_KEY` function variables are created and correct.
2. Use `res.json()` rather than `req.json()`.
3. Don't pass `error` to `res.json()` because it might not serialize correctly.
4. Use async/try/await/catch rather than promise/then/catch to make the code cleaner and clearer
5. If your function runs for 15 seconds before erroring, increase the timeout to 4 minutes so the execution doesn't time out, and you can catch the error.